# Time Machine cannot locate external disk

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have an **iMac11,2** running **MacOS 10.8.5**. Time Machine (TM) has made backup on a LaCie 320GB Firewire400 HDD for almost 2 years now. It stopped working 2 weeks ago, stuck on 'looking for drive'. My HDD is full, but I am quite sure it already deleted older backups successfully. I tried:

- to connect a new external HDD (Seagate 2TB with USB cover) and switch TM to this, formatted in MacOS extended,journalized (no encryption);
- to turn off TM, delete `/System/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`, turn on TM, reselect my disk; once again rebooting before turning on TM;
- entered StarWars mode, copied `com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` from my last working backup to my internal HDD;
- copied `Backups.backupdb` from the 320GB to the 2TB disk; I can enter StarWars mode and browse, but still the infinite 'looking for drive' message
- checked the drive permissions: 320GB's `Backups.backupdb` is `drwxr-xr-x+ root:staff`. 2TB is similar due to the copy. I am currently changing the 2TB's `Backups.backupdb` persmissions to `drwxrwxr-x+ root:staff` recursively, <s>but it takes some time, I will post the result later</s>. Took the night to do that, still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking. I would start by using `Disk Utility` to look at what is on your old HD. Assuming this is OK you should be able to copy to another HD.

Comment: To clarify my comment above I suggest copying the partition. There are a number of hidden files in addition to Backups.backupdb

Comment: @Milliways I can try that, but if the partition was corrupted, I will recopy the corruption... What I wanna try: erase the original 320GB and start over TM on it. If fails, upgrade to Maverick, maybe TM's settings get renewed?

Comment: `Disk Utility` has options to Verify and Repair partitions

Comment: verify found nothing wrong. Repaired anyway, no improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually upgraded from 10.8 to 10.10 (Apple having removed 10.9 from AppStore...). And Time Machine is now up and running. I'll never know what happened.